# Should I use the question sign in a phrase started with "I'm wondering..."?

Tags: indirect-question

Is it correct to use the question sign `?` for indirect questions started with the phrase "I'm wondering"?

For example,

> I am wondering if you know his name?

Formally this is not a question, because it starts with "I am wondering" but not "Am I wondering".

Comment: In this instance I would use it, since a question is implied. You do not necessarily require an  interrogative sentence to produce a question mark. 'Coffee?'

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what is referred to as an "embedded direct question", and I would not use the question mark.

When I read it with the question mark, it connotes to me that the person is pondering whether if they themselves are wondering.

From Garammar-monster.com:
I wonder whether Anne is going to the party.
(Embedded direct question: Is Anne going to the party?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as @WS2 states, since a question is implied, use of question mark is permissible/appears valid.

Sometimes interrogative sentences are actually declarative sentences that have a question mark at the end.

If you ask this type of question, the last syllable of the final word in the sentence is spoken with a rising intonation.

Here are a few examples.

•The bus has already **left**?

•The Saints won the *Super* **Bowl**?

•It’s snowing in **Florida**?

Comment: In general, your point is a fair one. But in your second example, I don't know a single native speaker who would emphasize *Bowl*. Normally, the stress would be on *Saints*, to express surprise or incredulity at their victory; if, unusually, you were surprised at *what* they won, the emphasis would probably be on the first syllable of *Super*